# Invalid signature al validar correo electrónico en laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

he implementado el modo Auth de Laravel en Laravel 8, y todo bien excepto la verificación de correo electrónico, que me da un error tipo 403, invalid signature.

He seguido varios consejos pero sigo sin solucionar este tema.

El controlador de verificación tiene este código:

```
   <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\VerifiesEmails;

class VerificationController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Email Verification Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling email verification for any
    | user that recently registered with the application. Emails may also
    | be re-sent if the user didn't receive the original email message.
    |
    */

    use VerifiesEmails;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after verification.
     *
     * @var string
     */
protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
    // protected $redirectTo = '/home';
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('signed')->only('verify');
        $this->middleware('throttle:6,1')->only('verify', 'resend');
    }
}
```

En el archivo .env, en la zona inicial, tengo esta configuración:

```
 APP_NAME="Mi primera web"
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:ssjJpF//hkEKTCiom9oVenO6LYFQPLMbOAwE0y6TGQc=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=https://miprimeraweb.es
APP_USE_HTTPS=true
LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

En routes/web:

```
 <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
// Route::get('/', function () {
//     // Only verified users may enter...
// })->middleware('verified');
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
Route::get('/logout', '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout');
```

El email llega correctamente pero al validar me da ese error, lo extraño es que para resetear la contraseña si funciona.

También he modificado el server NGINX, con esta solución=> [link](https://www.jesusamieiro.com/403-invalid-signature-when-i-try-to-verify-an-email-in-laravel/)

Por último, en el appServiceProvider.php

```
    <?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
     \URL::forceScheme('https');
    
    }
}
```

He probado casi todo, pero no doy con la tecla. Gracias.

Nota: el servidor de correo esta en otro servidor.

### Edición #1

El problema esta en esta línea    \URL::forceScheme('https');, sin embargo sin esta instrucción no me carga como https, ni siquiera con un middleware realizado para tal efecto. Si carga con protocolo http si valida el email.

Comment: No estás agregándole nada a la url en alguna parte del código? Algo como `$request->merge()`

Comment: He realizado una edición, el fallo es    \URL::forceScheme('https');

Comment: Te sugiero que procedas a responder tu propia pregunta, puesto que el comentario y la edición no tienen por objeto aclarar el problema sino dar una solución, y el día de mañana llegará un usuario con tu mismo problema, y a simple vista pensará (porque así se ve) que la duda nunca fue respondida.